# Android Concurrency, App dying after about 3 uses

Tags: java, android, networking, concurrency, executorservice

I'm developing an app with different views populated with data acquired from a Server API. As of right now, I've come up with a 'solution' as to how to make the most out of the multicore Android devices that are currently available. I thought that a Producer/Consumer strategy was the right choice for this problem. However I'm using as many consumers as the Phone has cores and when executing the application everything works fine. But in some cases the application dies and doesn't do anything when I launch it, if I clear the RAM on my device I can launch the application again.

Consumer run method:

```
while(true) {
            lock.lock();
    while(queuedOperations.isEmpty()) {
        ma.debug("Slave " + slaveId + " is waiting for requests.");
        try {
            slaveCondition.await();
            if(doTerminate) { return; }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    ma.debug("Executing Request... " + slaveId);
    JSONRequestParam[] params = queuedOperations.poll();
    ma.debug("Polled an item. " + slaveId);
    lock.unlock();
    ma.debug(request.execute(params)); // returns a String.
}
```

Using the following shutdown method:

```
public void destroy() {
        ma.debug("Terminating all external resources...");
        lock.lock();
        this.doTerminate = true;
        slaveCondition.signalAll();
        lock.unlock();
        try {
            service.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        service.shutdown();
}
```

The way I trigger the Consumers is by a signal from the Condition class. Here's the code:

```
public void submitRequest(JSONRequestParam... params) {
    lock.lock();
    queuedOperations.add(params);
    slaveCondition.signal();
    lock.unlock();
}
```

I overrided the onBackPressed method in the main activity as well;

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    try {
        JSONRequestManager.getInstance(this).destroy();
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

but to no avail. The application is very buggy and unstable. I have tried to find a replicate of this problem here and on numerous of different sites, couldn't find anything that helped. I'm almost sure there's no deadlocks in this application, I have a reasonable amount of experience working with concurrent applications, however Android is a tad bit different when it comes to threading...

Is there any hints or practices that I'm missing out? Why is the application working when the RAM is cleared and on first launch? Is there something jamming in the background? I really do not know. I hope you can tell!

Any help is **greatly** appreciated!

Comment: I doubt this will help, but is good practice to use locks in this format:
`try{lock.lock(); ...}
finally{ lock.unlock(); }`

Comment: Thanks for your input. I tried adding try{} finally{} blocks to all the locks, however I was unfortunately able to reproduce the error.

Comment: Could there be a `StrictMode` or similar default policy enforcement through another means which the app is violating, which may be causing this?

Comment: I have not set any of those by myself. It's just confusing because apparently the threads run in the background or aren't deallocated even though they are terminated in the application before shutdown.